# How to smartly detect undefined symbols when linking a plugin on GNU/Linux?

Tags: c, linux, macos, linker, ld

I have a program `foo` that can load plugins via `dlopen()`.  I'm writing one such plugin `foobar` that interfaces to functionality provided by a third-party library `libfoo`.

On Linux, I'm building `foobar` like this:

```
gcc -fpic -c -o foobar.o foobar.c
gcc -fpic -shared -o foobar.so foobar.o -lbar
```

So far so good.

The problem is that this doesn't detect undefined symbols, for example because of bugs in the code or mismatches between header files and library.  The link succeeds, and you only get an error later when you load the plugin or when you invoke something in the plugin (depending on `dlopen()` flags).

To detect undefined symbols in a shared library, one would normally use `-Wl,-z,defs` or perhaps `-Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined`.  But this will fail because it will also report symbols that are supposed to be found in the `foo` program at run time.  I would like to detect undefined symbols except those provided by the hosting program.

On Mac OS X, for example, this is done by the `-bundle_loader` option.  The equivalent link command would be

```
gcc -bundle -o foobar.so foobar.o -lbar -bundle_loader=foo
```

and that detects undefined symbols in the way I want.

How does one do this on GNU/Linux or with GNU ld in general?  (I have looked through all the options listed on the `ld` man page, but none looked promising.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that I know of to do this. However, if the structure of 'foo' is under your control, you could possibly move all of the logic in 'foo' into a new shared library that exports the proper symbols, and then link both your plugins and mainline against that library.